# vue routes lazy loading when deployed not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lazy-loading, webpack-2, code-splitting

After implementing lazy loading in my routes like this:

```
component: () => import('./pages/home/index/index.vue')
```

locally it kinda works (loses fonts on certain routes).

When code is deployed by CI/CD environment, any route that is setup with lazy loading is not loaded in browser , with this console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

After inspecting the problem, it points to `<head>` tags, and inside I have this:

```
<link href=/dist/static/css/app.4d19fef0c231f16b8783490b2895fe94.css rel=stylesheet><link href=/dist/static/css/app.1fa1a352ec9d24165aab94b33bba4db2.css rel=stylesheet>
```

which are split css files in final bundle.

So that tells me I haven't configured something nicely in webpack config perhaps ?

Help with this is appreciated.

webpack config is standard vue-cli config (this is prod config):

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  // The following line must be used for production because of the 
  // folder structure we have in the packaged app.  
  //context: __dirname + "/../../app",

  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
     // Eliminate comments
        comments: false,

    // Compression specific options
       compress: {
         // remove warnings
            warnings: false,

         // Drop console statements
            drop_console: true
       },
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin(),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

build prod settings:

```
 build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'),
//    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
//    assetsSubDirectory: '/static',
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
//    assetsPublicPath: '/app/dist/',
   assetsPublicPath: '/',
    // assetsPublicPath: '/dist/',
    fontPath: '/static',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
```

Comment: If you believe it's a problem with the webpack config, showing the webpack config would be helpful

Comment: added webpack.config.prod

Comment: Are you using a Vue Router for this?

Comment: yes, I do @RuChernChong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you are using `Vue Router` for your app.

Add `base: '/sub-directory/` into your Router code.

For example:

```
export default new Router({
  base: '/foo-bar/',
  routes
})
```

Also remember to set your public assets path in your webpack configuration file to have the `/sub-directory/`

Comment: right now I don't have base flag explicitly set in my router config, but I do have public assets path set to `'/dist'`. Should I just add the same to base router config ?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: I added `'/dist'` to router config , it's the same thing. However when I inspect  network folder structure I see something like this:

dist/static/js for js bundle and diststatic/js for chunks, perhaps that is the problem ? Perhaps I need to add `'/dist/'` ?

Also I don't see why locally this works, just does not work when deployed ?

Comment: with that fix, it actually works, but I guess I will just put both router base path and assets public path to `'/'` , since I don't need dist sub-route.

Comment: with `'/'` site doesnt work again, I pasted additional snippet with public assets file in the original post, can you check it and see what is not ok there ? I don't need sub routes I just need it to work with chunk files.

Comment: No. You do not need to add /dist

Comment: well, when I used `'/'` site is not working cause some of the assets are in dist/static/... and others are in static/..., and it's throwing index file again in those js files. 

What could be wrong in my assets path setup ? I pasted it in original post, would be appreciated if you could comment on that. Thanks.

Comment: For root directories, you do not need to add a base url since the base url by default is `/`. If your project is in a sub-directly, for example `/foo/`, then you will have to add the base as `base: /foo/,`

Comment: I fixed it in the end, basically I didn't have to change router config, in my case it should have stayed `'/'` , but my assetPublicPath instead of `'/data'` should have been `'/data/'`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed

Comment: Thanks for your help @RuChernChong

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed problem with modifying `assetsPublicPath: '/dist',` to `assetsPublicPath: '/dist/',`.

Main problem was that my tree structure should have been `dist/static/...` and it was `diststatic/...` for chunk files

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Where is `assetsPublicPath` in which file it lies?